# Setup IPv6 in IPv4 tunnel on DLink DIR-615

Tags: ipv6

Recently I wanted to setup IPv6 for my home network. I signed up for tunnelbroker.net service and was provided with IPs.
Then I configured the IP address in my DIR-615. 
But It's not working..

Screenshot of IPv6 config (router):
[image]

Screenshot of my Win 8 network Config:
[image]

I also tested [here](http://test-ipv6.com) but failed...

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

If your hardware is D-Link DIR-615 rev. C1 or D-Link DIR-615 rev. C2. You can install Openwrt and configure IPv6.

*Be careful, it can brick your router.*

Details are here: [http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/d-link/dir-615?s[]=dir&s[]=615](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/d-link/dir-615?s%5B%5D=dir&s%5B%5D=615)

Openwrt firmware: http://downloads.openwrt.org/attitude_adjustment/12.09/ar71xx/generic/
(file looks like "openwrt-ar71xx-generic-dir-615-c1-squashfs-factory.bin",C1 and C2 use same firmware)

Configure IPv6: http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/ipv6

[On my router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMHTx.jpg) it's is D-Link DIR-615 rev. C2.

Comment: Mine is E4 . Is it supported?